# 500 server error installing ExpressionEngine 5.2.4 (MAMP Pro)

Tags: install, error-500

I downloaded ExpressionEngine and moved files to my local server (Mamp Pro). I can see/enter /admin.php but after hitting the Install button it takes about 30 seconds and the process aborts with a server error on this URL http://my-site.local:8888/admin.php?C=wizard&M=do_install&language=english

The apache log says

```
[Thu Jul 04 17:15:07 2019] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: comm with server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php7.0.33.fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec), referer: http://my-site.local:8888/admin.php
[Thu Jul 04 17:15:07 2019] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php7.0.33.fcgi", referer: http://my-site.local:8888/admin.php
```

The DB is completely empty, so I guess nothing really happens. There are no entries in the PHP log.

I tried different PHP version (7.0 and 7.2) and different browsers. Before I tested with the ee_wirzard and saw everything green.

The mysql server doesn't run on the default port, but I can't enter the mysql host or a port anywhere. Perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: Your problem seems to be related to Mamp and no  from ExpressionEngine. So I guess, you will have more chance to solve your issue asling on Mamp foruns.

Comment: I had no errors with WordPress, Concrete5, ProcessWire, PyroCMS, CraftCMS, Mgento, OctobreCMS … but yeah, it has nothing to do with ExpressionEngine. However, I just wanted to test. Don't need it

Comment: Yes, sometimes could be just a tiny configuration problem. Never encountered the problem you described with MAMP and Expression Engine.

Comment: You could try the same thing using AMPPS ( https://www.ampps.com/ ) as your local environment.

Comment: No, I won't use it all. Everything about ExpressionEngine makes a bad picture. The community looks very small (sorry guys), the forum is bad as hell and doesn't work and the product does look like 2010. I may be wrong, but I won't count on a sinking ship.

Answer (score 0):

I would set everything (ports) to default before giving up on it. I am using MAMP Pro (version 5.3(17956)) on Mojave with ExpressionEngine versions 3.5.17 and various versions of ExpressionEngine 5.x.

- "MySQL 5.7.25 is configured to use port 3306"
- Php version (default) 7.2.14

Oh yea, so is this MAMP Pro 5 for Mac or MAMAP Pro 4 for Windows? I use both, but I seem to have more issues in the Win version... could be though just that I am not quite as used to Win as Mac. And they are different versions for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks, but all in all the picture I got from ExpressionEngine was rather bad